# CDT API: Issues looking up values using the IIndex

Tags: java, eclipse-cdt

Part of a program I am working on requires looking up preprocessor macros by name, and then getting their values. I opted to use the CDT Indexer API. In order to make sure I am on the right track, I wrote a test method that does nothing but create a simple C file and confirm that it can find certain symbols in the index. However, I failed to get that test to run properly. Attempting to use IIndex.findBindings(char[], IndexFilter, IProgressMonitor) returns empty arrays for symbols that I know exist in the AST because they are part of the example file in the test method.

I can't post the exact test method because I use some custom classes and it would be overkill to post all of them, so I will just post the important code. First, my example file:

```
    final String exampleCode =
        "#define HEAVY 20\n" +
        "#define TEST 5\n" +
        "void function() { }\n" +
        "int main() { return 0; }\n";
    IFile exampleFile = testProject.getFile("findCodeFromIndex.c");
    exampleFile.create(new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleCode.getBytes("UTF-8") ), true, null);
```

I have a custom class that automatically gets the IASTTranslationUnit from that file. The translation unit is fine (I can see the nodes making up everything except the macros). I get the index from that AST, and the code I use to look up in the index is

```
    try {
        index.acquireReadLock();
        returnBinding = index.findBindings(name.toCharArray(), IndexFilter.ALL, null);

    ... catch stuff... 
    } finally {
        index.releaseReadLock();
    }
```

Where 'name' is going to be either "HEAVY", "TEST", or "function". None of them are found, despite existing in the example test c file.

I am guessing that the issue is the index is not rebuilt, which causes findBindings to return an empty array even if I know the given variable name exists in the AST.

My current attempt to start up the indexer looks like this:

```
    final ICProject cProject = CoreModel.getDefault().getCModel().getCProject(testProject.getName());
    CCorePlugin.getIndexManager().reindex(cProject);
    CCorePlugin.getIndexManager().joinIndexer(IIndexManager.FOREVER, new NullProgressMonitor() );
```

Question Breakdown:

1) Is my method for searching the index sound?

2) If the issue is the index needing to be rebuilt, how should I properly force the index to be up to date for my test methods? Otherwise, what exactly is the reason I am not resolving the bindings for macros/functions I know exist?

Comment: After some further testing, it seems the root issue is that since my test method does not create a true C project with a source folder, the indexer just ignores the C file as part of the overall project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my own issue so I will post it here. I was correct in my comment that the lack of the project being a proper C project hindered the Indexer from working properly, however I also discovered I had to use a different method in the indexer to get the macros I needed.

**Setting up the test enviornment:**

Here is the code I have that creates a basic C project. The only purpose it serves is to allow the indexer to work for test methods. Still, it is large:

```
public static IProject createBareCProject(String name) throws Exception {
    IProject bareProjectHandle = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(name);
    IProjectDescription description =
        bareProjectHandle.getWorkspace().newProjectDescription("TestProject");

    description.setLocationURI(bareProjectHandle.getLocationURI() );

    IProject bareProject =
        CCorePlugin.getDefault().createCDTProject(description, bareProjectHandle, new NullProgressMonitor() );

    IManagedBuildInfo buildInfo = ManagedBuildManager.createBuildInfo(bareProject);
    IManagedProject projectManaged =
        ManagedBuildManager
            .createManagedProject(bareProject, 
                                  ManagedBuildManager.getExtensionProjectType("cdt.managedbuild.target.gnu.mingw.exe") );

    List<IConfiguration> configs = getValidConfigsForPlatform();
    IConfiguration config = 
        projectManaged.createConfiguration(
                configs.get(0), 
                ManagedBuildManager.calculateChildId(configs.get(0).getId(), null));

    ICProjectDescription cDescription = 
        CoreModel.getDefault().getProjectDescriptionManager().createProjectDescription(bareProject, false);

    ICConfigurationDescription cConfigDescription = 
        cDescription.createConfiguration(ManagedBuildManager.CFG_DATA_PROVIDER_ID, config.getConfigurationData() );

    cDescription.setActiveConfiguration(cConfigDescription);
    cConfigDescription.setSourceEntries(null);
    IFolder srcFolder = bareProject.getFolder("src");
    srcFolder.create(true, true, null);
    ICSourceEntry srcFolderEntry = new CSourceEntry(srcFolder, null, ICSettingEntry.RESOLVED);
    cConfigDescription.setSourceEntries(new ICSourceEntry[] { srcFolderEntry });

    buildInfo.setManagedProject(projectManaged);

    cDescription.setCdtProjectCreated();

    IIndexManager indexMgr = CCorePlugin.getIndexManager();
    ICProject cProject = CoreModel.getDefault().getCModel().getCProject(bareProject.getName() );
    indexMgr.setIndexerId(cProject, IPDOMManager.ID_FAST_INDEXER);

    CoreModel.getDefault().setProjectDescription(bareProject, cDescription);

    ManagedBuildManager.setDefaultConfiguration(bareProject, config );
    ManagedBuildManager.setSelectedConfiguration(bareProject, config );

    ManagedBuildManager.setNewProjectVersion(bareProject);

    ManagedBuildManager.saveBuildInfo(bareProject, true);

    return bareProject;

}
```

As I discovered when debugging, it is indeed important to set proper configurations and descriptions as the indexer was postponed so long as the project didn't have those features set. To get the configurations for the platform as a starting point for an initial configuration:

```
public static List<IConfiguration> getValidConfigsForPlatform() {
    List<IConfiguration> configurations = 
        new ArrayList<IConfiguration>();

    for (IConfiguration cfg : ManagedBuildManager.getExtensionConfigurations() ) {
        IToolChain currentToolChain =
            cfg.getToolChain();

        if ( (currentToolChain != null )                           && 
             (ManagedBuildManager.isPlatformOk(currentToolChain) ) &&
             (currentToolChain.isSupported() )                     ) {

            configurations.add(cfg);
        }
    }
    return configurations;
}
```

This basically answers the second part of the question, and thus I can create a c project for the purposes of testing code using the index. The testing code still needs to do some work.

**Testing Code**

I create files in the the "src" folder in the project (created in the above code), and I either have to name them .c, or if I want to name them .h have them included by some .c file (otherwise the indexer won't see them). Finally, I can populate the files with some test code. To answer number 1,

I need to block on both auto refresh jobs in Eclipse and then the index:

```
public static void forceIndexUpdate(IProject project) throws Exception {
    ICProject cProject = CoreModel.getDefault().create(project);
    Job.getJobManager().join(ResourcesPlugin.FAMILY_AUTO_REFRESH, null);
    CCorePlugin.getIndexManager().reindex(cProject);
    CCorePlugin.getIndexManager().joinIndexer(IIndexManager.FOREVER, new NullProgressMonitor() );
    assertTrue(CCorePlugin.getIndexManager().isIndexerIdle() );
    assertFalse(CCorePlugin.getIndexManager().isIndexerSetupPostponed(cProject));
}
```

After I change the files in the project. This makes sure Eclipse is refreshed, and then makes sure the indexer completes without being postponed. Finally, I can run tests depending on the indexer.

And the last point, I was wrong about using IBinding. The correct way in which I was able to get the macros was using the method `IIndex.findMacros(char[] name, IndexFilter filter, IProgressMonitor monitor)`

I hope this helps at least someone out there. I would also appreciate it if there was some feedback regarding the validity of this solution, as this is simply the first solution I managed to create that worked. Just to confirm, I am not testing the indexer itself, but rather code I wrote that uses the indexer and I want to test it under as realistic conditions as I can given how critical it is.